# Not able to scroll down while drag and drop if the page has more than one vertical scroll bar

Tags: jquery, backbone-views

The canvas area not getting scroll down

Hi,

I am not able to scroll down the canvas to drop my dragged value.Actually i done
my code while draggable as below . But in my page i have two scroll bars vetically.How to scroll down my canvas to drop. See my screen shot

$(".dnd-preview-draggable-answer").draggable({

revert: "invalid",

tolerance: "pointer",

appendTo: "body",

scroll : "true",

cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the traditional way, your code will look like this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
                 revert: "invalid",
                 tolerance: "pointer",
                 appendTo: $(".inner-content-that-will-be-scrolled"),
                 scroll : "true",
                 cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },
                 drag: function( event, ui ) { 
                     var draggableY = parseInt($('.draggable').css('top'));  
                     var scrolled = $('.inner-content-that-will-be-scrolled').innerHeight();
                     if (draggableY + 50 >= y2) { 
                         //Start scrolling
                         $('.page').animate({
                            scrollTop:  scrolled},
                            {duration: 5000,
                            step: function() {
                                var x = parseInt($('.draggable').css('left'));
                                var y = parseInt($('.draggable').css('top'));   
                                //detect stop scrolling
                                if ((y + 20 < y2) || y > y2 + 20 || x > x2 || x < x1) {
                                    //cancel animation
                                    $(this).stop();
                                 }
                               }
                         });
                     }
                 }
             });
         });
```

Comment: But it seems to be the contents get hidden. I want to scroll my inner div while dragging

Comment: this changes a lot, I have updated the code above to match your expectations.